# How can I add nominal values on attributes?

Tags: java, machine-learning, instance, weka

I want to add some attributes which has nominal int values. But I don't know how to declare that it's nominal and add possible values.

I made ArrayList and converted possible int values into string and added it. But I don't think it's okay to do so.

```
public class ModelClassifier {
    private ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
    private ArrayList<String> classVal = new ArrayList<String>();  
    // nominal attribute, classval
    private ArrayList<String> methods = new ArrayList<String>();  
    // nominal attribute
    private ArrayList<String> winners = new ArrayList<String>();   
    // nominal attribute
    private Instances dataRaw;

    public ModelClassifier() {
        for(int i=0; i<32; ++i) classVal.add(i+"");
        for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) methods.add(i+"");
        for(int i=0; i<6; ++i) winners.add(i+""); 

        attributes.add(new Attribute("model", classVal));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("method", methods));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate1_1"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate1_2"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate2_1"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate2_2"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate3_1"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate3_2"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate4_1"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate4_2"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate5_1"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate5_2"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate6_1"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("candidate6_2"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("avg"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("dev"));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("winner", winners));

        dataRaw = new Instances("TestInstances", attributes, 0);
        dataRaw.setClassIndex(0);
    }

    public Instances createInstance(double[] instanceValue1) {
        dataRaw.clear();
        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue1)); 
        return dataRaw;
    }
}
```

This code actually worked, but I'm highly suspicious about it. I think I'm missing something. I post part of my arff file I used to train the model.

Comment: attribute model {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}
attribute method {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
attribute candidate1_1 real        ...
attribute candidate6_2 real
attribute avg real
attribute dev real
attribute winner {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Answer (score 0):

try `ArrayList<Integer>`
and learn about autoboxing and unboxing in java from google.

---

You shall let us know about what Attribute are you dealing with first...
[image: "Attribute"s]

Comment: problem is that Attribute constructor only takes ArrayList<String> so ArrayList<Integer> doesn't work

Comment: @SuhMyungKyo but you have to let me know what Attribute in what package/module did you use. There are a lot of classes namde Attribute in this world...

Comment: This is about weka Attribute. weka is a tool for data analysis and machine learning.